# Why using value function in xml where condition is returning null value in tsql

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have the following XML I need to parse in tsql

The issue lies in the where condition. only the first record is validated in the where condition. If I change the GLNominalAccount value to [2] the second node is validated. Is there a way I can loop over all the nodes using the where condition. I am looking only GLNominalAccount value that match the where condition across the whole nodes. Thanks

```
<JournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2"
<JELine sequence="1">
<Amount currencyID="USD">-100.000</Amount>
<FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">-100.000</FunctionalAmount>
<ReportingCurrencyAmount     currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
<GLAccount>
    <GLNominalAccount>1005690</GLNominalAccount>
    <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
    </AccountingChartReference>
</GLAccount>
</JELine>
<JELine sequence="2">
<Amount currencyID="USD">100.000</Amount>
<FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">100.000</FunctionalAmount>
<ReportingCurrencyAmount     currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
<GLAccount>
    <GLNominalAccount>34180050</GLNominalAccount>
    <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
    </AccountingChartReference>
</GLAccount>
</JELine>
</JournalEntry>
```

Below is my tsql code

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2')
SELECT ParamValues.SSD.value('GLNominalAccount[1]', 'varchar(8)') 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount') AS ParamValues(SSD) 

WHERE @xmldata.value(N'(/JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' ,'varchar(max)') LIKE '2%'


OR @xmldata.value('(//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' , 'varchar(8)') LIKE '3%'
OR @xmldata.value('(//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' , 'varchar(8)') LIKE '4%'
OR @xmldata.value('(//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' , 'varchar(8)') LIKE '6%'
OR @xmldata.value('(//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' , 'varchar(8)') LIKE '7%'
OR @xmldata.value('(//JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]' , 'varchar(8)') LIKE '8%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw: Your example XML is missing a closing `>`...

No need to loop or iterate. the `.nodes()`-function will return all *same-level-nodes* as rows:

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<JournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2">
  <JELine sequence="1">
    <Amount currencyID="USD">-100.000</Amount>
    <FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">-100.000</FunctionalAmount>
    <ReportingCurrencyAmount currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
    <GLAccount>
      <GLNominalAccount>1005690</GLNominalAccount>
      <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
      </AccountingChartReference>
    </GLAccount>
  </JELine>
  <JELine sequence="2">
    <Amount currencyID="USD">100.000</Amount>
    <FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">100.000</FunctionalAmount>
    <ReportingCurrencyAmount currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
    <GLAccount>
      <GLNominalAccount>34180050</GLNominalAccount>
      <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
      </AccountingChartReference>
    </GLAccount>
  </JELine>
</JournalEntry>';
```

--The query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2')
SELECT j.value('@sequence','int') AS JELine_Sequence
      ,j.value('(Amount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Amount_CurrencyID
      ,j.value('(Amount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS Amount
      ,j.value('(FunctionalAmount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FunctionalAmount_CurrencyID
      ,j.value('(FunctionalAmount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS FunctionalAmount
      ,j.value('(ReportingCurrencyAmount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ReportingCurrencyAmount_CurrencyID
      ,j.value('(ReportingCurrencyAmount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS ReportingCurrencyAmount
      ,j.value('(GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]','bigint') AS GLNominalAccount
      ,j.value('(GLAccount/AccountingChartReference/ID/@accountingEntity)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS accountingEntity
      ,j.value('(GLAccount/AccountingChartReference/ID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS AccountID

FROM @xml.nodes('JournalEntry/JELine') AS A(j)
```

The result

```
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
| JELine_Sequence | Amount_CurrencyID | Amount    | FunctionalAmount_CurrencyID | FunctionalAmount | ReportingCurrencyAmount_CurrencyID | ReportingCurrencyAmount | GLNominalAccount | accountingEntity | AccountID |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
| 1               | USD               | -100.0000 | USD                         | -100.0000        | USD                                | 100.0000                | 1005690          | T00              | T00       |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
| 2               | USD               | 100.0000  | USD                         | 100.0000         | USD                                | 100.0000                | 34180050         | T00              | T00       |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
```

### UPDATE MyQuery as CTE

I understand your attempt as follows: The number must start with 2, or with 3, or with 4.... Any number but 0,1,5 and 9. This is easier put in a `NOT IN()`-clause

With this you'd get the query as derived table, which you can filter with a *normal `WHERE`-clause`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2')
,myCTE AS
(
    SELECT j.value('@sequence','int') AS JELine_Sequence
          ,j.value('(Amount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Amount_CurrencyID
          ,j.value('(Amount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS Amount
          ,j.value('(FunctionalAmount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FunctionalAmount_CurrencyID
          ,j.value('(FunctionalAmount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS FunctionalAmount
          ,j.value('(ReportingCurrencyAmount/@currencyID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ReportingCurrencyAmount_CurrencyID
          ,j.value('(ReportingCurrencyAmount)[1]','decimal(14,4)') AS ReportingCurrencyAmount
          ,j.value('(GLAccount/GLNominalAccount)[1]','bigint') AS GLNominalAccount
          ,j.value('(GLAccount/AccountingChartReference/ID/@accountingEntity)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS accountingEntity
          ,j.value('(GLAccount/AccountingChartReference/ID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS AccountID

    FROM @xml.nodes('JournalEntry/JELine') AS A(j)
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE
WHERE LEFT(GLNominalAccount,1) NOT IN('0','1','5','9')
```

In general it was better to set the filter as early as possible. This was the `.nodes()`-function in order not to return nodes, which do not fit to the filter. But in this case I think it's better to return all nodes and filter them afterwards (as done here). If the XML contains a lot of `<JELine>`-nodes it might be better to change this...

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo .The issue I am having is to implement a where condition to get only the values I need. In this case account Nr 34180050 I need to match the where condition with '3%'

Comment: @SysIntegrator007 The easiest way was to wrap my query as CTE and use a *normal `WHERE`-clause in the outer query. Do you need help with this?

Comment: @SysIntegrator007 Another approach was to inlcude your condition as `XQuery` into the `XPath` in `.nodes()`....

Comment: . Yes please I used temp table to solve it.. which is not quite good. Please let me have our CTE example

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your WHERE condition to:

```
WHERE ParamValues.SSD.value('GLNominalAccount[1]', 'varchar(8)') LIKE '[2-46-8]%'
```

Here's a fully working solution (note my comments)

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = 
'<JournalEntry xmlns="http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2">
<JELine sequence="1">
<Amount currencyID="USD">-100.000</Amount>
<FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">-100.000</FunctionalAmount>
<ReportingCurrencyAmount     currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
<GLAccount>
    <GLNominalAccount>1005690</GLNominalAccount>
    <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
    </AccountingChartReference>
</GLAccount>
</JELine>
<JELine sequence="2">
<Amount currencyID="USD">100.000</Amount>
<FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">100.000</FunctionalAmount>
<ReportingCurrencyAmount     currencyID="USD">100.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
<GLAccount>
    <GLNominalAccount>34180050</GLNominalAccount>
    <AccountingChartReference>
        <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
    </AccountingChartReference>
</GLAccount>
</JELine>
</JournalEntry>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schema.mycompany.com/Info/2')
SELECT ParamValues.SSD.value('GLNominalAccount[1]', 'varchar(8)') 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('JournalEntry/JELine/GLAccount') AS ParamValues(SSD) -- dont need the "//"
WHERE ParamValues.SSD.value('GLNominalAccount[1]', 'varchar(8)') LIKE '[2-46-8]%' -- simplier WHERE clause
```